# Can not insert and select integers from database(Android)

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

MyDBClass.java

```
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Listyu";

// Table Name
private static final String TABLE_COUNTRY = "paylist";
public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {"ID","Name","Amount"};

public myDBClass(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    // Create Table Name
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COUNTRY +
              "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
              " Amount INTEGER,"+ 
              " Name TEXT(100));");
    Log.d("CREATE TABLE","Create Table Successfully.");
}

// Insert Data
public long InsertData(String name, int amnt) {
     try {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // Write Data

        ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();

        Val.put("Name", name);
        Val.put("Amount", amnt);

        long rows = db.insert(TABLE_COUNTRY, null, Val);

        db.close();
        return rows; // return rows inserted.
     }  catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
     }

}

// Select Data
public Cursor SelectData() {
     try {
         SQLiteDatabase db;
         db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // Read Data

         Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_COUNTRY, new String[] { "ID AS _id, *" },null, null, null, null, null);

            if(cursor != null) {
                return cursor;
            } else {
                return null;
            }

     } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
     }
}
```

Create.java

In this class I inserted name(string) and amount(int) as follows,

```
String note = et.getText().toString();
String amount = ett.getText().toString();
int converted = Integer.parseInt(amount);
myDb.InsertData(note,converted);
```

List.java

In this class, I call all amounts inserted in a list view as follows, the program doesn't work when list.java is opened.

```
myDb = new myDBClass(this);
ListView lisView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1); 
final Cursor c = myDb.SelectData();
lisView1.setAdapter(new CountryAdapter(this, c ));
registerForContextMenu(lisView1);

public class CountryAdapter extends CursorAdapter 
{   
        private Cursor cursor;
        public CountryAdapter(Context context, Cursor cur) {
        super(context, cur , 0);
        this.cursor = cur;


                                                      }

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
            // ColID
        TextView txtID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textsv);
            txtID.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Amount")));


        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
            bindView(view, context, cursor);
            return view;

        }
```

Comment: make like this  Val.put("Amount",""+ amnt);

Comment: If you step through the app, does the returned cursor actually contain data or is it empty?

Comment: no, there is no data inserted

Comment: Print out the number that is returned from your insert method. If it's negative 1, no data is inserted, and there is an error you ignored

Comment: thank you @cricket_007 . BTW instead of considering Amount as an int, I dealt it with TEXT type and it works fine.

Comment: I have removed a column form database and then installed the app to phone root. Then while trying to insert it didn't took values because database was not updated. So I changed database version and it worked fine.